# changing the border color of a label by tapping and dragging

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I want to be able to change the border color of my label when it is tapped and dragged and when it is not being tapped and dragged, the border color should return to its previous colour. I have employed both pan and tap gesture recognisers but I have no idea in writing the code to change this. This is my code below:

```
(void)change:(id)sender {


    CGRect labelFrame = CGRectMake(230, 240, 300, 30);

    UILabel *headingLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];


    headingLabel.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    headingLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    headingLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    headingLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];


    [self.view addSubview:headingLabel];
    [headingLabel setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    headingLabel.text = _textField.text;



    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
    [headingLabel addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    [headingLabel addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];    
}

(void)panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)paramSender{
    if (paramSender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded &&
        paramSender.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed){
        CGPoint location = [paramSender locationInView:paramSender.view.superview];
        paramSender.view.center = location;
    }
}

(void) tapDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)paramSender {
    NSUInteger touchCounter = 0;
    for (touchCounter = 0;
         touchCounter < paramSender.numberOfTouchesRequired;
         touchCounter++){
        CGPoint touchPoint =
        [paramSender locationOfTouch:touchCounter
                          inView:paramSender.view];
    }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the view delegate methods :

touchesBegan, touchesEnd..

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: also from the change method, i want to autofit every label created to the text in the label...